# basic bash conditional statements

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements

I know I'm doing something wrong here:

```
for i in `cat $resFile | awk -F: '{print $1}' | awk '{print $2}'`; do
    echo $i
    if [ 1 < $i ] ; then
        /usr/bin/mutt -s "SR Sampling Message" emailaddress@hotmail.com < $resFile ; else
        echo "everything's fine"
    fi
done
```

the if statement returns true every time, I need it to follow the negative result. It should be obvious, I'm just missing it.

The `$resFile` looks like this:

```
10.254.254.254  2:34
10.254.254.253  2:34
10.254.254.252  2:34
10.254.254.251  2:34
10.254.254.250  3:41 
10.254.254.249  3:41
10.254.254.248  3:41
```

I always get output no matter what I put as the threshold for time. I know it's all hacky and I'm using `awk`, I'm just having trouble with the conditional

Comment: again one abused `cat` ;) (and your `for` loop will not work), use `$(....commands....)` Please, specify what you want get from your $resfile

Comment: that's true. I'm not certain I know a better way, can you show me the way and the light?

Comment: @user3550476 [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically points out this and other basic problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

less than operator ( < ) wont work with [ ] 
you should use

`if [ $i -lt 1 ]`

if you want to use < operator use (()) brackets 
like `if (( $i > 1 )); then`